# Running c++ program using micropython on esp-32

Tags: c++, esp32, micropython

I want to run my C++ programs using micropython which run on esp-32 board perfectly. Now I want to run it using micropython. For that I am referring to

https://github.com/stinos/micropython-wrap this wrapper.

I created foo.cpp and test.py

```
#include <micropython-wrap-master/functionwrapper.h>

//function we want to call from within a MicroPython script
std::vector< std::string > FunctionToBeCalled ( std::vector< std::string > vec )
{
  for( auto& v : vec )
    v += "TRANSFORM";
  return vec;
}

//function names are declared in structs
struct CppFunction
{
  func_name_def( TransformList )
};

extern "C"
{
  void RegisterMyModule(void)
  {
    //register a module named 'foo'
    auto mod = upywrap::CreateModule( "foo" );

    //register our function with the name 'TransformList'
    //conversion of a MicroPython list of strings is done automatically
    upywrap::FunctionWrapper wrapfunc( mod );
    wrapfunc.Def< CppFunction::TransformList >( FunctionToBeCalled );
  }
}
```

test.py

```
import foo

print(foo.TransformList(['a', 'b']))  # Prints ['aTRANSFORM', 'bTRANSFORM']
```

But whatever way I try it get

```
ERROR   thonny.plugins.micropython.backend: Problem adding Expr handlers
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/thonny/plugins/micropython/backend.py", line 1235, in _add_expression_statement_handlers
    root = ast.parse(source)
  File "/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/ast.py", line 50, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, flags,
  File "<unknown>", line 1
    python test1.py
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What I understand, before I can run cpp program I need to run makefile. But there is no steps available which explains me how to build makefile using micropython on esp-32

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The repo you linked to doesn't let you "run" a C++ program from within MicroPython. You cannot just import C or C++ code into MicroPython at runtime, as you were trying to. C and C++ must be compiled using a C/C++ compiler.

The repo you referenced lets you extend MicroPython by compiling your own C++ functions and including them in the MicroPython firmware. To do that you have to rebuild MicroPython itself on a Linux, Mac or Windows computer.

As its README says:

> Integrating and Building
>
> First clone this repository alongside the MicroPython repository, then
> refer to the way the tests module is built and create your own modules
> in the same way.

To use it, you need to clone [the MicroPython repo](https://github.com/micropython/micropython/), create your own modules in it, rebuild MicroPython, then re-flash your ESP32 with your new MicroPython firmware.

You can find more information on building MicroPython and on MicroPython modules in the MicroPython repository.

Comment: thanks a lot for giving me correct guideline. This is really helpful. Do you have any reference link which explains how to add c++ module and guide me on how to rebuild the micropython